# GraphView - graphviewseries null

Tags: android, arrays, graph, android-graphview

my grapviewseries seems to be always null even though i have values inside my graphhviewdata

This is my code here :

```
GraphViewData []graphViewData = new GraphViewData[1000] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < listprice.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("date", String.valueOf(listdate.get(i)));
            Log.e("price",String.valueOf( listprice.get(i)));
            graphViewData[i] = new GraphViewData(listdate.get(i), listprice.get(i));

        }

        GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries( graphViewData);


        GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(getActivity() // context
                , "" // heading
        );
        ((LineGraphView) graphView).setDrawDataPoints(true);
        ((LineGraphView) graphView).setDataPointsRadius(15f);
        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.addView(graphView);
```

These are the errors that are given to me :

```
11-14 00:02:10.559: E/AndroidRuntime(14809): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 00:02:10.559: E/AndroidRuntime(14809): at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries.checkValueOrder(GraphViewSeries.java:199)
11-14 00:02:10.559: E/AndroidRuntime(14809):    at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries.<init>(GraphViewSeries.java:91)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array of 1000 elements

```
GraphViewData []graphViewData = new GraphViewData[1000] ;
```

but you're only setting values for the first `listprice.size()` elements. The rest are null.

Either make your array have only `listprice.size()` elements, or set the currently null values to some appropriate non-null value such as `GraphViewData(0.0,0.0)`.